TensorFlow.js : unable to find content for text generation using models like gpt2 in nodejs
I m new to ML or AI, just started learning
so my task is to make chatbot using models(locally in our system for data privacy) like gpt2 or any other that present on internet and then fine tune them by our own dataset. so it can perform according to our requirement. in NODEJS OR javascript(NO PYTHON).
So, till now i have gone through tensorflowJS docs and accordingly i have downloaded LLM model locally in system like gpt2(.h5 format) and then converted it into TF.JS format(.json and .bin files) and now want to perform text generation but unable to find any code or content for the same.
Now, my first QUESTON:- is it possible to perform text generation or make chatbot from locally models and then finetunning in nodejs or javascript(no python) using tensorflow.js or not
if its possible, then tell me next steps or any way or any resources or any library other than tensorflowJS to make this work done...
OR USING PYTHON IS ONLY SOLUTION???...
